# How to catch all the errors in all views?

Tags: python, django, exception

I know we can use try and except function to catch the error. But everyday I monitor the sentry, the system always get an exception in any views. As usual I put try and except to catch the errors in the views.

My question is. Is it possible to catch all the errors from any views in just one function? Then the user will redirect to another page. Where is the best place to do this? I'm thinking about middleware but I don't have knowledge about it.

Answer (score 5):

yes,  can handle all exceptions from any view. try Googling "django middleware exception",  you'll find many solutions .

Comment: middleware is very simple,  it won't take more than 20minutes to write a middleware class.  just try

Comment: But I don't know how to start. Do you have any link?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/   that's official document about middleware